# How to replace colored text in docx using open xml in C#?

Tags: c#, openxml, document, docx

I tried this but it doesn't replace colored text:

```
using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open("yosi.docx", true))
{
    var document = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document;

    foreach(var text in document.Descendants<Text>())
    {
        if (text.Text.Contains("eeee"))
        {
            text.Text = text.Text.Replace("eeee", "aaaa");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The reason you are required to add a certain amount of text to the question is to try to get you to add enough details so that we understand what you are trying to do and what problems you are running into.  Adding a link to an unrelated movie script doesn't help at all.  Please don't do that.

Comment: Is the text `eeee` always guaranteed to be colored in your document?  One problem I see in your code is that you never save your changes.  You need to add `doc.Save();` at the end (inside the closing brace of the `using` statement).

Comment: Also, while word might display multiple text strings consecutively, they might be wrapped in different tags in the file format.